# Image field: Force at least/exactly two images per field

Tags: entities, media

I can easily set the maximum number of elements per field, but is there an easy way to specify the *minimum* value?
For now, I have an Image field, and I want at least two images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already answer [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52059/how-to-set-minimum-number-of-required-fields)

You can do it by using [**Field validation**](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) Module.

The following validators are listed:

> - Regular expression
> - Numeric values (optionally specify min and / or max value)
> - length (optionally specify min and / or max length)
> - number of words (optionally specify min and / or max words )
> - Plain text (disallow tags)
> - Must be empty (Anti-Spam: Hide with CSS)
> - Words blacklist
> - number of selections (optionally specify min and / or max selections
>     )
> - Unique
> - Match against a field
> - Match against a property
> - Specific value(s)
> - Require at least one of several fields
> - Equal values on multiple fields
> - Unique values on multiple fields
> - PHP Code (powerfull but dangerous)
> - URL (support internal path and external url validation)
> - Email
> - Pattern (Regular expression lite)
> - Date range2

Hope this will help you